# How to start eventListeners at the end of a MovieClip?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have my game. First frame is where the start-game button is placed - it takes me to frame 2 where I have my game level. Upon entry in the second frame plays a fade MovieClip, and at the end of it I'll `MovieClip(root).addChild(character);` to enter the playable character.

My problem is that eventListeners for the keyboard events are in the main timeline code and if I'll press any key that moves the character it will start moving even though it did not appeared yet because the fade didn't finished.

Is there a way to fix this, or where do I do wrong?

I'll post bits of my code if it is required. THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to fix this, but here's what I'd suggest:

1) On your main timeline, create a function to add your character and the keyboard listeners:

```
function beginPlaying():void {
    addChild(character);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
    // etc
}
```

2) In your fade MovieClip, at the end, you only need to call this function:

```
MovieClip(root).beginPlaying();
```

This should solve your current problem, and hopefully be easier to deal with any similar future problem.

Comment: That is quite simple. I should've thought of that. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

This solution works but it has a potential problem because the code that controls your game is now partially hidden inside some MovieClip. I did that myself many times and often had troubles when I needed to change, find or remember something.

A slightly better solution is not calling some root function directly but simply dispatching an Event:

```
dispatchEvent(Event.COMPLETE); // or any custom event
```

So now your movieclip does not have to call a particular function in the root, it just throws an Event, and your timeline can have a listener for it.

Furthermove, it is advisable to get rid of all code in the fader movieclip. Again, you can add a listener for the `Event.ENTER_FRAME` in the root, and just check if the fader has finished `(fader.currentFrame == fader.totalFrames)`

Comment: I've did it as you suggested, it works just as fine. For anyone wating to use this method: add an event listener for it to work - movieclip_name.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function), and place your code-to-happen in that function.